# Vertical Progress Steps with CSS

Tags: reactjs, css, flexbox, responsive

I have react components printing an itinerary from a train and I need to unify the circles with a vertical line like this:

[image]

I need to unify those nodes (circles with a vertical bar) and was looking for an idea. I'm using flex and the items are being rendered using a react component that includes 3 subcomponents (one with the time, one with the node - circle and one with the Station and real time).

I have to write the css from scratch (using maximum flexbox or grid).

Thank you in advance.

Comment: Add minimal html and css

Comment: May be you can use <ul><li> tags and set custom image icon for a bullet point..

Comment: what about using these components: http://ahlechandre.github.io/mdl-stepper/

Comment: The thing is that I need to have a stepper that isn't ordered, for example the point of origin and destination is backgrounded as black and the position of where the train is marked with an icon. All of this is already done from scratch. I just need an idea of how to unify all those nodes with a vertical line.

Answer (score 24, accepted):

My attempt.

I would go with an unordered list where time and description are children of `flexbox` list-items. Dot and vertical line can be easily drawn using pseudoelements (properly stacked).

```css
.events li { 
  display: flex; 
  color: #999;
}

.events time { 
  position: relative;
  padding: 0 1.5em;  }

.events time::after { 
   content: "";
   position: absolute;
   z-index: 2;
   right: 0;
   top: 0;
   transform: translateX(50%);
   border-radius: 50%;
   background: #fff;
   border: 1px #ccc solid;
   width: .8em;
   height: .8em;
}


.events span {
  padding: 0 1.5em 1.5em 1.5em;
  position: relative;
}

.events span::before {
   content: "";
   position: absolute;
   z-index: 1;
   left: 0;
   height: 100%;
   border-left: 1px #ccc solid;
}

.events strong {
   display: block;
   font-weight: bolder;
}

.events { margin: 1em; width: 50%; }
.events, 
.events *::before, 
.events *::after { box-sizing: border-box; font-family: arial; }
```

```html
<ul class="events">
  <li>
    <time datetime="10:03">10:03</time> 
    <span><strong>Bat &amp; Ball</strong> On time</span></li>
    
  <li>
    <time datetime="10:03">10:03</time> 
    <span><strong>Bat &amp; Ball</strong> On time</span></li>
  
  <li>
    <time datetime="10:03">10:03</time> 
    <span><strong>Bat &amp; Ball</strong> On time and other text that may span over 2 lines</span></li>
  
  <li>
    <time datetime="10:03">10:03</time> 
    <span><strong>Bat &amp; Ball</strong> On time</span></li>
  
  <li>
    <time datetime="10:03">10:03</time> 
    <span><strong>Bat &amp; Ball</strong> On time</span></li>
  
  <li>
    <time datetime="10:03">10:03</time> 
    <span><strong>Bat &amp; Ball</strong> On time</span></li>
</ul>
```

Answer (score 2):

You could use a border on a wrapper like so:

```css
.timeline-wrapper {
  margin-left: 1.5rem;
  border-left: 3px solid #ddd;
}
.node {
  padding-left: .5rem;
  padding-bottom: 1.5rem;
  position: relative;
}
.node h3, .node p {
  margin: 0;
}
.node::before {
  content: "";
  width: .5rem;
  height: .5rem;
  background: #fff;
  border: 2px solid #ccc;
  border-radius: 50%;
  position: absolute;
  top: .3rem;
  left: -.5rem;
}
```

```html
<div class="timeline-wrapper">
  <div class="node">
    <h3>Title</h3>
    <p>Status / Time</p>
  </div>
  <div class="node">
    <h3>Title</h3>
    <p>Status / Time</p>
  </div>
  <div class="node">
    <h3>Title</h3>
    <p>Status / Time</p>
  </div>
  <div class="node">
    <h3>Title</h3>
    <p>Status / Time</p>
  </div>
  <div class="node">
    <h3>Title</h3>
    <p>Status / Time</p>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

The circles can be drawn using divs with border radius and then two circular divs and be seperated by another div with side border color highlighted.

Comment: I already have the Circles drawn and positioned, the only thing thats left is passing a vertical line connecting all of them. The rest has been handled. But thank you!

Comment: Yes this can be drawn with the div in between with a border color.

Comment: use css animation keyframes to show the drawing animation to be more awesome than adding divs with border radius